# Indefinite Integration of $x\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, radicals

I was wondering how to find out $$\int x\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\,dx$$

I was thinking of substitution $x=\sin^2t$, which helps with $1-x$. But then I cannot get rid of the denominator $1+x$.

Comment: What is your background? What have you tried?

Comment: And what did you wonder?

Comment: What is the simplest change of variable you could use for getting rid of the radical ?

Comment: I was thinking of letting x = $sin t^2$, but it didn't work out, I cannot get rid of the denominator.

Comment: Multiply numerator & denominator by $\sqrt {1-x }$ also not $ (x^2}^' - 2 x ) $

Comment: Multiply numerator & denominator by $\sqrt {1-x }$ also note $ (x^2}^{\prime} = 2 x ) $

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Try the substitution

$$\frac{1-x}{1+x}=u^2$$

As Claude Leibovici hinted, that will remove the square root sign and give you a rational expression to integrate.

Answer (score 2):

HINT... Try substituting $x=\cos 2\theta$ and then some fairly straightforward trig manipulation...

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=\sin\theta, \;dx=\cos\theta\; d\theta$ to get

$\displaystyle\int x\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}dx=\int\sin\theta\sqrt{\frac{1-\sin\theta}{1+\sin\theta}}\cos\theta d\theta=\int\sin\theta\sqrt{\frac{(1-\sin\theta)^2}{\cos^2\theta}}\cos\theta d\theta$

$\displaystyle=\int\sin\theta(1-\sin\theta) d\theta=\int\left(\sin\theta-\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos 2\theta)\right) d\theta=-\cos\theta-\frac{1}{2}\theta+\frac{1}{4}\sin2\theta+C$

$\displaystyle=-\cos\theta-\frac{1}{2}\theta+\frac{1}{2}\sin\theta\cos\theta+C=-\sqrt{1-x^2}-\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}x+\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{1-x^2}+C$