# Evaluate: $\int x\sqrt{\frac{a-x}{a+x}}\hspace{1mm}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate: $$\int x\sqrt{\dfrac{a-x}{a+x}}\hspace{1mm}\mathrm{d}x$$

I don't know where to start. Hints/suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Try $$x=a\cos2t$$

Comment: You can let $x=au$ and then use http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1724727

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $x=a\sin t$ and $dx=a\cos t dt$

$\displaystyle\int x\sqrt{\dfrac{a-x}{a+x}}dx=\int a\sin t\sqrt{\dfrac{a-a\sin t}{a+a\sin t}} a\cos t dt=a^2\int \sin t\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\sin t}{1+\sin t}} \cos t dt$

Now, multiply the inside of the square root by $\frac{1-\sin t}{1-\sin t}$

$\displaystyle a^2\int \sin t\sqrt{\dfrac{(1-\sin t)^2}{1-\sin^2 t}} \cos t dt= a^2\int \sin t\dfrac{(1-\sin t)}{\cos t}\cos t  dt$

Can you proceed?

Comment: I took the liberty of making a change in your answer, but feel free to change it back if you want to.

Comment: @user84413 Thank you! I got lost somewhere in the copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{a-x}{a+x} = u^2 \rightarrow x = a\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2} \rightarrow dx = \frac{-4au}{(1+u^2)^2}du
$$
$$
\int x\sqrt{\dfrac{a-x}{a+x}}\hspace{1mm}\mathrm{d}x = \int a\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2} u\hspace{1mm}\frac{-4au}{(1+u^2)^2}du = -4a^2 \int \frac{u^2(1-u^2)}{(1+u^2)^3}du =
$$
$$
-4a^2 \int \frac{u^2(1-u^2)}{(1+u^2)^3}du = -4a^2[\int \frac{du}{1+u^2} + \int \frac{3du}{(1+u^2)^2} + \int \frac{-2du}{(1+u^2)^3}] 
$$
For each integral apply $u=\tan\theta$
$$
\int \frac{du}{1+u^2} = \arctan(u)
$$
$$
\int \frac{3du}{(1+u^2)^2} = 1/2 (u/(u^2+1)+\arctan(u))
$$
$$
\int \frac{-2du}{(1+u^2)^3} =  1/8 ((u (3 u^2+5))/(u^2+1)^2+3 \arctan(u))
$$
Now substitute $u = \sqrt{\frac{a-x}{a+x}} $

Answer (score -1):

This is not the exact problem, but I am sure this will help: http://www.slader.com/textbook/9780618149186-larson-calculus-7th-edition/418/exercises/40b/

Main Idea is to substitute $x = a\sin \theta$

Comment: While this link may help to solve the problem, it is more helpful to post in the information in the link.

Comment: Made an edit, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @clawhauser A bit more detail that would be good. The idea is that your answer should be self-contained on this site (in case the link ever goes dead).